# Flex AMF Data/Services Error

Tags: java, spring, apache-flex, blazeds, amf

After stumbling my way through setting up a BlazeDS service, I was finally able to get the list of services through the Flex Builder Data/Services Wizzard.  However when testing any of the services, I get the Error popup of

```
> "InvocationTargetException:There was an error while invoking the
> operation. Check your operation inputs or server code and try invoking
> the operation again. 
> 
> Reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/portlets-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/messagebroker/amf/
```

I could not find anyone else with a similar issue, and am unfamiliar with services setup. Below are my configurations.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can post config files if it will help, i was getting improper code format errors trying to insert them in this single post.

This service I am testing does not reach the function in the server, it is throwing this error before getting that far...

I have also noticed that I cannot run the flex application through a web browser using the standard run configuration in eclipse as it tries to target:

> [http://127.0.0.1:8080/portlets-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/messagebroker/amf/FlexMissionsOverview/MissionsPortlet.html][1]

Which throws a 404 error on tomcat since the file does not exist there.  Are these possibly connected?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Added Details based on feedback:**

Yes, the project name is "FlexMissionsOverview" with a Base Flex Application Called "MissionsPortlet"(.mxml).

The webapp is deployed to "webapps/portlets-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/"

**Compiler settings below:**

> -services "C:\liferay\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\portlets-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\flex\services-config.xml" -locale en_US
>   -show-deprecation-warnings=false
>   -show-binding-warnings=false

Note: I am setting my project back up to where I had gotten to by the time of this post, if anything changes I will make another edit.

**services-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<services-config>

    <services>
        <service-include file-path="remoting-config.xml" />
        <service-include file-path="proxy-config.xml" />
        <service-include file-path="messaging-config.xml" />        
    </services>

    <factories>
        <factory id="spring" class="flex.samples.factories.SpringFactory"/>
    </factories>



    <services>
        <service id="remoting-service" class="flex.messaging.services.RemotingService">
            <adapters>
                <adapter-definition id="java-object"
                    class="flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter"
                    default="true" />
            </adapters>
            <default-channels>
                <channel ref="my-amf" />
            </default-channels>
        </service>
    </services>

    <channels>
        <channel-definition id="my-amf"
            class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
            <endpoint
                url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf"
                class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint" />
            <properties>
                <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>
                <polling-enabled>false</polling-enabled>
            </properties>
        </channel-definition>
    </channels>

    <logging>
        <!-- You may also use flex.messaging.log.ServletLogTarget -->
        <target class="flex.messaging.log.ConsoleTarget" level="Error">
            <properties>
                <prefix>[BlazeDS] </prefix>
                <includeDate>false</includeDate>
                <includeTime>false</includeTime>
                <includeLevel>true</includeLevel>
                <includeCategory>false</includeCategory>
            </properties>
            <filters>
                <pattern>Endpoint.</pattern>
                <pattern>Service.</pattern>
                <pattern>Configuration</pattern>
            </filters>
        </target>
    </logging>

</services-config>
```

Pointing to the file directly on the tomcat server seems to work fine for testing the Flex Application via Eclipse, but I am still getting the same "FileNotFoundException" When trying to test the BlazeDS Services in the Data/Services Wizard in FlashBuilder.

Is there any indication of what the FileNotFoundException is coming from when trying to test the services? It may be some of the config information, but I am not positive, since I am used to these Exceptions saying what file it could not find.

The only class that I have in my project that is referenced above is the two listener classes, the other classes I believe come from my maven dependencies.

Comment: Can you add the flex compiler options here? Also, what is the folder name of the project in the server?

Comment: FlexMissionsOverview/MissionsPortlet.html is this the project name/proeject start files?

Comment: @Zeus I have added the requested details above.

Comment: Aalso passtee d serices-conf file. Try to clean buid the proj. Compiler options look ok

Comment: You have to change the run configuration manually. and point it to http://127.0.0.1:8080/portlets-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MissionPortlet.html

Comment: @Zeus Thanks for the tip to point the run config at the MXML Application directly, but the main problem still exists. Edited post to add more details.

Comment: Are you using spring blazeds integration?

Comment: @Zeus Bump...pretty desperate